# How do I make a nested scroll not scroll the entire page?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, overflow

Have a look please at the snippet below.
I managed to make the `main` scroll without its `header`, but I am unable to make the list on the right scroll **internally** without the rest of `main`.
I would like the list of boxes on the right, to scroll on its own, leaving its pink header and the rest of `main` in place.

I tried applying `overflow-auto` to the `div` that holds the children but that didn't work.
I also tried setting `overflow-hidden` on **its** parent, but that just blocks scrolling altogether.

I know there are a lot of question like this one out there, but none of the solutions I found worked for me so I recreated my case here.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex flex-col w-full h-full">
  <header class="h-16 bg-red-300"></header>
  <main class="flex-grow w-full overflow-auto bg-green-300">
    <div class="flex w-full h-full bg-blue-300">
      <div class="h-full w-1/3 bg-purple-300"></div>
      <div class="h-full w-1/3 flex-grow bg-yellow-300"></div>
      <div class="h-full w-1/3 flex flex-col bg-indigo-300">
        <header class="h-12 bg-pink-300"></header>
        <div class="flex-grow bg-gray-300 w-full h-full p-3">
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, but the new `overscroll-behavior` property might be what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior

Answer (score 0):

- Apply `flex-shrink: 0` to the pink `<header>` so it has a non-zero `height`.
- Apply `overflow-y: auto` to the `<div>` container of the list to have the list scrollable.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex flex-col w-full h-full">
  <header class="h-16 bg-red-300"></header>
  <main class="flex-grow w-full overflow-auto bg-green-300">
    <div class="flex w-full h-full bg-blue-300">
      <div class="h-full w-1/3 bg-purple-300"></div>
      <div class="h-full w-1/3 flex-grow bg-yellow-300"></div>
      <div class="h-full w-1/3 flex flex-col bg-indigo-300">
        <header class="h-12 bg-pink-300 shrink-0"></header>
        <div class="flex-grow bg-gray-300 w-full h-full p-3 overflow-y-auto">
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
          <div class="w-full border border-blue h-10"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correct, you just want the grey list on the right side to scroll internally, without making the whole body scrollable as is the current case.

I see that you already tried applying `overflow-auto` to the div that holds the children, and setting `overflow-hidden` on its parent. I don't know why it didn't work for you, but I made similar same changes to your code, and it worked. Maybe you didn't apply both the properties at same time.

First, set the `main` element as `overflow-hidden`.

```
<main class="w-full flex-grow overflow-hidden bg-green-300">
```

And second, set the grey list part as `overflow-auto`.

```
<div class="h-full w-full flex-grow overflow-auto bg-gray-300 p-3">
```

Here is the [tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/zbLH7kCgDv) with this change.